# jquery conflict between drop down boxes/read more and menu

Tags: jquery

I have two drop down boxes on the same page that work in tandem.  The options shown in the second list are based on the selection made in the first box. On the same page there is also a read more/read less section and a flyout mega menu.  Read more/read less and the menu work fine until I add the two drop down boxes.  Once the drop down boxes are added the flyout menu will not open and the hidden content of the read more/read less is exposed and will not close.  The two drop down boxes would not work until I addeed   jQuery.noConflict(true).  Once added the drop down boxes work but menu and read more/read less stopped working.  Below is the code I am using for the drop down boxes.

I have tried moving " jQuery.noConflict(true) " around and placing the closing tag in diffrent areas with no success.  My goal is to have the two drop down boxes working along with the read more/read less and the flyout menu.  Thanks very much for any advice you can offer.

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="small-2 small-centered columns">
 <form name="doublecombo">
 <p><select name="example" size="1" onChange="redirect(this.options.selectedIndex)">
 <option>Technology Sites</option>
 <option>News Sites</option>
 <option>Search Engines</option>
 </select>

 <script type="text/javascript">juery.noConflict(true)</script>
 <select name="stage2" size="1">
 <option value="http://javascriptkit.com">JavaScript Kit</option>
 <option value="http://www.news.com">News.com</option>
 <option value="http://www.wired.com">Wired News</option>
 </select>
 </p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <script>
 <!--
 /*
 Double Combo Script Credit
 By JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
 Over 200+ free JavaScripts here!
 */
var groups=document.doublecombo.example.options.length
var group=new Array(groups)
for (i=0; i<groups; i++)
    group[i]=new Array()
group[0][0]=new Option("JavaScript Kit","http://javascriptkit.com")
group[0][1]=new Option("News.com","http://www.news.com")
group[0][2]=new Option("Wired News","http://www.wired.com")
group[1][0]=new Option("CNN","http://www.cnn.com")
group[1][1]=new Option("ABC News","http://www.abcnews.com")
group[2][0]=new Option("Hotbot","http://www.hotbot.com")
group[2][1]=new Option("Infoseek","http://www.infoseek.com")
group[2][2]=new Option("Excite","http://www.excite.com")
group[2][3]=new Option("Lycos","http://www.lycos.com")
var temp=document.doublecombo.stage2
function redirect(x){
for (m=temp.options.length-1;m>0;m--)
temp.options[m]=null
for (i=0;i<group[x].length;i++){
temp.options[i]=new Option(group[x][i].text,group[x][i].value)
}
temp.options[0].selected=true
}
function go(){
location=temp.options[temp.selectedIndex].value
}
//-->
</script>
</form>
```

Comment: So what's the actual problem?

Comment: Thanks for your question.  The problem is the flyout menu and read more/read less that is on the same page as the drop down boxes will not work once the drop down boxes are placed on the page.